# Word for opposite of boss that is not pejorative?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm developing an app and cannot figure out a good word for the "underlings" of a boss which doesn't sound so pejorative. I've thought of *supervisee*, but that sounds archaic and I don't like how it's so close to *supervisor*.

Comment: There are a lot of synonyms in this area: report; employee; worker; staff; hire...

Comment: I think I'll just have to go with "employee", though that's still a little more general than I would like since executives/managers/supervisors are still technically employees. "Report" and "hire" each have common uses that interfere with their meaning in my app. "Worker" already has usage in CS and sounds objectifying. "Staff" is a pretty good alternative, but I would like something that is "s-plural"-able